# Can't find drivers for EW-7811UAC on Ubuntu 16.10. Realtek rtl8812AU

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, kernel, realtek

I recently got a EW-7811UAC. I have Ubuntu 16.10 and I'm unable to find a driver for my kernel. As far as it seems all of the drivers for its realtek rtl8812AU aren't coded for the latest kernel for ubuntu 16.10 Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak. I have the Linux kernel 4.8.0-36-generic.

- Edimax webpage:
- http://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811uac/

I tried both and they failed. The github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU driver give an output of

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping... 
Building module: cleaning build area.... 
'make'....(bad exit status: 2) 
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812AU: 4.3.14 not found 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build/make.log for more information."
```

I ran `dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}`

The contents of make.log are

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic' CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’ scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build/core/rtw_cmd.o]
Error 1 Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build' failed make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic' Makefile:1576: recipe for target 'modules' failed make: *** [modules] Error 2"
```

- I ended up downgrading my kernel and reinstalling gcc and it fixed my issue. The driver is now working correctly. I used this driver https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8821au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edimax driver to too old to run with Ubuntu 16.10. You need an updated driver. Here are two recommendations...

https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU

https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: Did you manually upgrade your kernel to 4.8.0-36-generic? I've got 16.10 and the latest is -34. I'm running the same rtl8812au/4.3.14 and it works fine. Temporarily bypass dkms, and go to the source folder and do a `make` and then a `make clean` when you're done. See if the plain make works there.

Comment: ps: you can check https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rtl8812AU&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults for other drivers.